# adobe air signal-processing using alchemy

Tags: flash, air, signal-processing, alchemy

Im aware that it is possible to use C++ (audio) digital signal processing in adobe flash, using Alchemy (as a way to compile the C++ code). However, my questions is, is it possible to use Flash/Alchemy (dsp) and package that as an Air app (for IOS/Android)?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I used myself as3Crypto wrapper (Alchemy version) without problem on both Android and iOS, others also successfully used Box2D Alchemy port in mobile games, hence it might work in your case too, you'll just process byteArray sound data.

Anyway before starting your project you can test ex: Ogg Vorbis Alchemy functionality, here is good article with sourse codes
http://labs.byhook.com/2011/02/22/ogg-vorbis-encoder-decoder-for-flash/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried ALF Library http://music.ece.drexel.edu/ALFdocs/files/Flash/ALF-as.html - it works just fine in simulator on the dev machine, but whenever I launch it on mobile device in release mode -- the performance is disastrous.